# Number in Circle How to resize font

Tags: html, css

I have a circle which shows number inside it and i can't handle font size.

Here is my code:

```
  span.blue {
        background: #5EA226;
        border-radius: 0.8em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bolder;
        line-height: 4em;
        text-align: center;
        width: 4em;
        font-size: 250%;
        font-size: initial;
```

And HTML code:

```
<span class="blue">5 </span>
```

I want to get bigger font size but whatever i try, font size is same so how can i play with font size?

Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is based on the font-size of the span in your example because you are using `em` values.

As such, you cannot increase the text size without increasing the size of everything else.

The solution (well, the first I thought of0 is to add an internal span like so.

```css
span.green {
  background: #5EA226;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
span.green > span {
  font-size: 250%;
  line-height: .625;
}
```

```html
<span class="green">5</span>

<span class="green"><span>5</span></span>
```

However, this will also slightly distort the effect so you should try adjusting the line-height to compensate.

Alternative Option - Use a defined height rather than `line-height` and `display: table-cell;`. This avoid teh need for any line-height adjustments.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/snc98nck/3/)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `font-size: initial;`, it is overriding your `font-size: 250%;`.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use % for the property font-size:24px/pt/e.m

Answer (score 1):

Use this style

```
   span.blue {
    background: #5EA226;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bolder;
    line-height:250px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 150px;
   }
```

this might solve your problem.